# Count records in one table that don't match another table

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table `t1` that looks like this:

```
business_id    customer_id    customer_zip
        1000           100           10019
        1000           101           10020
        1000           102           10021
        1000           103           10022
        1000           104           10023 --customers 100 and 101 from t2 match here based on zip
        1000           105           10023 --customers 100 and 101 from t2 match here based on zip
```

And another table `t2` that looks like this:

```
customer_id    txn_zip
       100       10023
       101       10023
       200       00012
```

I'm trying to select all records from `t2` for which the `customer_id` field does not match, but the zip codes do.

The following query is wrong because it double counts customers 100 and 101:

```
SELECT
    a.business_id,
    count(b.customer_id) as cnt
FROM t1 a 
INNER JOIN t2 b 
ON (a.customer_id!=b.customer_id AND a.customer=b.txn_zip)
GROUP BY a.business_id;
```

This query results in:

```
business_id    cnt 
       1000      4
```

Which is wrong - it's matching `customer_id` 100 and 101 twice each, resulting in a count of 4 because their zip code 10023 shows up twice in table `t1` without a match on the customer_id.

Here's the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
business_id    cnt 
       1000      2
```

I could use `COUNT(DISTINCT b.customer_id)`, but the production tables are HUGE; is there a better way to do the join so that it's not joining the `customer_id` fields multiple times each in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`, but you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.business_id, count(b.customer_id) as cnt
FROM t1 a LEFT JOIN
     t2 b 
     ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.customer = b.txn_zip
GROUP BY a.business_id;
```

EDIT:

If I understand correctly, you only want to count zips that are in the second table.  And then count the rows in `a` where the customer does not match.  I would suggest `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT a.business_id, count(*) as cnt
FROM t1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t2 b
                  WHERE a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND          a.customer = b.txn_zip
                 ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t2 b
              WHERE a.customer = b.txn_zip
             )
GROUP BY a.business_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to find the count of customers from t2 whose zip codes match t1, but whose customer IDs don't match; your answer requires matches on both. However, if we change a.customer_id = b.customer_id in your answer to a.customer_id != b.customer_id, we still have a count of 4.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns 100 and 101 IDs:

```
with 
t1 as (
select stack(6, 
        1000, 100, 10019,
        1000, 101, 10020,
        1000, 102, 10021,
        1000, 103, 10022,
        1000, 104, 10023, 
        1000, 105, 10023
        ) as ( business_id, customer_id, customer_zip)
),
t2 as (
select stack(3, 
       100, 10023,
       101, 10023,
       200, 00012
        ) as ( customer_id, txn_zip)
)

select b.customer_id
from
(
select  collect_set(customer_id) as customers, 
        customer_zip
  from t1 a
 group by customer_zip
) a inner join t2 b on a.customer_zip=b.txn_zip
where not array_contains(a.customers, b.customer_id)
;
```